# Is there a way to obtain a full list of atoms from a ligand residue?

Tags: python, biopython

I'm currently working on parsing PDB file which consists of protein pocket and ligand molecule.
The residue name of every ligand is set as 'UNL', and PDB file looks like the following:

```
HETATM   82  C   UNL     1      26.597 -14.916  44.878  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM   83  C   UNL     1      26.531 -16.231  44.189  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM   84  C   UNL     1      27.120 -15.808  42.893  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM   85  C   UNL     1      28.329 -15.071  43.387  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM   86  C   UNL     1      28.931 -14.170  42.366  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM   87  O   UNL     1      26.682 -15.216  46.247  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   88  O   UNL     1      27.464 -17.006  44.905  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   89  O   UNL     1      27.392 -16.979  42.137  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   90  O   UNL     1      27.766 -14.291  44.394  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   91  O   UNL     1      30.134 -13.666  42.869  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   92  P   UNL     1      30.766 -12.347  42.334  1.00  0.00           P
HETATM   93  O   UNL     1      29.854 -11.258  42.524  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   94  O   UNL     1      31.832 -12.240  43.274  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   95  O   UNL     1      31.114 -12.735  40.988  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   96  P   UNL     1      25.791 -14.349  47.212  1.00  0.00           P
HETATM   97  O   UNL     1      25.136 -13.375  46.321  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   98  O   UNL     1      24.939 -15.263  47.985  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM   99  O   UNL     1      27.047 -13.730  48.313  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM  100  P   UNL     1      27.751 -12.152  47.857  1.00  0.00           P
HETATM  101  O   UNL     1      26.680 -11.123  47.845  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM  102  O   UNL     1      28.472 -12.318  46.604  1.00  0.00           O
HETATM  103  O   UNL     1      28.661 -12.022  49.014  1.00  0.00           O
```

I tried to obtain the list of atoms simply by

```
from Bio.PDB.PDBParser import PDBParser
import numpy as np

structure = PDBParser(QUIET=True).get_structure('X', 'sample.pdb')

lig_res = [r for r in structure.get_residues() if r.get_resname() == 'UNL'][0]
print(lig_res.get_unpacked_list())
ligand_atoms = [a.get_coord() for a in lig_res.get_atoms()]
print(len(ligand_atoms))
print(np.array(ligand_atoms))
```

but, what I obtained was

```
[<Atom C>, <Atom O>, <Atom P>]
3
[[ 26.597 -14.916  44.878]
 [ 26.682 -15.216  46.247]
 [ 30.766 -12.347  42.334]]
```

only three atoms, which seems like the representative atoms of the ligand.

Is there a way to obtain a full list of atoms from a ligand residue?

Thank you.

Comment: That is not enough information for me. When I copy your code into my IDE, I get an error at 'structure'. Please provide a minimal example. This means code that everybody can execute to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Oh, I updated the code part.

Answer (score 1):

I think the PDB file is not valid. According to https://www.cgl.ucsf.edu/chimera/docs/UsersGuide/tutorials/pdbintro.html
"Each atom in a residue must be uniquely identifiable. Two atoms in the same residue can only have the same name if they have different alternate location identifiers."

You are always getting the first atom named C, O and P. When I change line 2 of your PDB file to read

```
HETATM   83  C1  UNL     1      26.531 -16.231  44.189  1.00  0.00           C
```

your script returns 4 atoms.
I think you must change the name of the atoms so that they are unique. Either you fix the script that created the PDB file (if it is under your control) or you write a script that fixes the PDB file by proper renaming.

Using :

`structure = PDBParser(QUIET=False).get_structure('X', 'sample.pdb')`

NOTE : `QUIET = False`

you'll get these kind of warnings , code proceeds after warnings:

```
......./lib/pythonX:X/site-packages/Bio/PDB/PDBParser.py:416: PDBConstructionWarning: PDBConstructionException: Atom C defined twice in residue <Residue UNL het=H_UNL resseq=1 icode= > at line 2.
Exception ignored.
Some atoms or residues may be missing in the data structure.
  warnings.warn(
......./lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/Bio/PDB/PDBParser.py:416: PDBConstructionWarning: PDBConstructionException: Atom C defined twice in residue <Residue UNL het=H_UNL resseq=1 icode= > at line 3.
Exception ignored.
Some atoms or residues may be missing in the data structure.
......
......
```

Using :

`structure = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE = False , QUIET=False).get_structure('X', 'sample.pdb')`

NOTE : `PERMISSIVE = False , QUIET = False`

you'll get these kind of error/exception , code breaks after exception:

```
......
......
..../lib/python3.8/site-packages/Bio/PDB/PDBParser.py", line 425, in _handle_PDB_exception
    raise PDBConstructionException(message) from None

PDBConstructionException: Atom C defined twice in residue <Residue UNL het=H_UNL resseq=1 icode= > at line 2.
```